# How to Resize HTML Pages and Images

Tags: html, css

I have an html page that I'm displaying the data in 2 columns. I have an image in the right column. When the page is shrunk the image drops to the bottom of the screen instead of continually getting smaller. I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Here is the code:

```
<div id="page_content" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;overflow: auto;">
      <div style="position:relative;float:left;width:50%;padding: 0 10px 10px 20px;overflow: auto;">
    some text
      </div>
      <div style="position:relative;float:right;width:47%; padding-right: 5px;overflow: auto;">

                    <map id="FPMap0" name="FPMap0">
                    <area coords="453, 343, 579, 411" href="M/default.html" shape="rect" />
                    <area coords="455, 427, 580, 494" href="P/default.html" shape="rect" />
                    <area coords="17, 42, 164, 102" href="#1._Plan" shape="rect" />
                    <area coords="5, 150, 185, 269" href="#2._Mod" shape="rect" />
                    <area coords="284, 98, 430, 166" href="#3._Prep" shape="rect" />
                    <area coords="286, 176, 431, 241" href="#4._Cond" shape="rect" />
                    <area coords="285, 347, 423, 412" href="#5._Close" shape="rect" />
                    <area coords="286, 432, 423, 496" href="#6._Collect" shape="rect" />
                    <area coords="285, 525, 425, 569" href="#7._Analyze" shape="rect" />
                    </map>

                    <img  id="the_pic" style="vertical-align:top; top:5px; max-width:100%;max-height:100%;overflow: auto;"  src="images/img8.jpg" usemap="#FPMap0"/>

                    </div>
      </div>
```

What I'm trying to do is to allow the image to resize as small as needed without shifting.

Comment: Place your codes within these tags `` <<-- (the symbol key before the number '1' in your keyboard)

Comment: It was multiple lines, so indenting four spaces is more appropriate.

Comment: Can you see the code now?

Comment: Try using `%s` for your `padding:` instead of pixels. When you resize smaller, at some point your padding in pixels is going to be more than the `3%` that you left in your widths and this will push the image below your first `div`.

Comment: Damn that was quick. Works perfectly!!! Thanks Brett